# Palm oil usage statistics

Tags: oil, vegetable-oil, vegetarianism

Can someone point me to a resource that would detail what is palm oil being used for, preferably with some % indicators?

A staunch meat eater has been boldly proclaiming that being vegetarian or vegan is bad for the environment because of palm oil (which is used in some vegan substitutes and, she claims, is consumed more by people who substitute animal fats with plant-derived fats) destruction of the rain forest. I am under the impression that you eat the same or even more palm oil if you are a regular meat eater (i.e. buying processed foods etc) but I lack a scientific basis for that assumption.

Comment: The question is fine, but you don't need it refute that ridiculous statement. Obviously the person does not take into account the amount of imported soy etc that goes into animal food. Just look at what's happening in many South American countries with cut down forests, diseases from heavy pesticide use, and violent  practices against the native population that protests.

Comment: Related: [What is palm oil mostly used for?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/5262/3379)

Comment: Since I can't answer your direct request for statistics I'll leave a comment here. I have had that argument when someone was trying to tell me that I am unduly taking the higher ground. If the meat-eater's concern is that rainforests are being destroyed, that is actually true of even cattle  and goat herders. More forests are being destroyed for cultivation and animal husbandry. Heck, even Chocolates. So forget meat or veganism, eating chocolates is an indirect cause. That is just an arrogant person's way of saying 'my life, my wish' and 'meat eating is actually better'.

Comment: A lot of palm kernel meal is used to produce animal feed. It may not count as palm oil, but it is from the same source. https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2011/may/09/pet-food-asian-rainforest